# Test Class Cannot Find @RestResource Web Service Class

Tags: rest-api, webservices, rest, rest-service

I have a @RestResource web service class that works fine in the real world, and works fine from Workbench, and its test class runs without errors, yet the test class does not actually run the web service class at all, so it has 0% coverage.

The web service class uses RestContext instead of parameters, and is in a sandbox. Consequently I am specifying the requestURI in the test, as described below. I have tried both the MyDomain and regular URIs. Everything runs, yet nothing is covered. The test class just isn't 'seeing' the actual class somehow. Pulling my hair out.

What am I missing?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SquareService/V1')

global class SquareCustomerWebService{
   
    @HttpPost
    global static void CustomerMethod(){  
        
        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>> hit SquareService');
        
        SquareHookClass SquareHook = (SquareHookClass) system.JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString().replace('object','Object1') , SquareHookClass.class);     
            system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(SquareHook) );
        
        if(SquareHook.type == 'customer.created'){...}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
    static void TestSquareCustomerWebService() {
        
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        
            request.requestUri ='https://cs35.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/SquareService/V1';
            request.httpMethod = 'POST';
            request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf('{'+
                                                  '"merchant_id": "MLVA9WV6PHTBD",'+
                                                  '"type": "customer.created",'+...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method after setting the RestContext.

SquareCustomerWebService.CustomerMethod();

Comment: Ha, the doc left that part out of their intial test example, geez. Thank you!

// Set up a test request
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
// Set request properties
request.requestUri =
    'https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/'
    + recordId;
request.httpMethod = 'GET';
// Set other properties, such as parameters
request.params.put('status', 'Working');
// more awesome code here....
// Finally, assign the request to RestContext if used
RestContext.request = request;

Answer (score 1):

`System.RestContext` is not the same as `System.RestRequest`.

To be able to successfully test your `@RestResource` annotated method, you need to feed Salesforce the appropriate data (that is, a `System.RestContext`).

In effect, there's not much different that you need to do here, as `System.RestContext` can be though of as a wrapper containing both a `System.RestRequest` and a `System.RestResponse`.

Additionally, as per usual, your test method needs to cause the method you want to test to be executed. Your test should resemble the following:

```java
@isTest
static void myTest(){
    System.RestRequest req = new System.RestRequest();

    // Not 100% sure that creating and using a RestResponse is necessary
    // Just doing this to be safe
    System.RestResponse res = new System.RestResponse();

    // Set up the RestContext for the method being tested to use
    System.RestContext context = new System.RestContext();
    context.request = req;
    context.response = res;

    req.setBody('{"my":"json payload"}');
    // I don't think setting the content-type header is strictly necessary, but
    //   it's probably still a good idea
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // As with virtually every test method, you should directly call the method
    //   you wish to test
    // Being annotated with @RestResource, it'll automatically pick up the
    //   RestContext you  build earlier in the test
    SquareCustomerWebService.CustomerMethod();
    
    // Don't forget to make assertions (the most important part of unit testing)
}
```